# Migrate from C# MVC to .net core Entity framework7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

If an application is built using C# MVC pattern with SQL database. Is it possible to migrate to .net core/asp.net core Entity framework 7 using postgreSQL database

Comment: short answer - yes it's possible. It should not be very difficult unless you using some specific functions in MS SQL

Comment: Yes. Do you have a specific question?